# HC-06 module does not receive data from Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: bluetooth, python, raspberry-pi-pico, micropython, hc-05

So I have a project that I'm currently working on and I am also using the *HC-06* module as a part of the communication process between the *Raspberry Pi Pico* and my application.
A while ago when I was working on my project I have changed some cables between the *HC-06* connector and the *Pico* and after that it just stopped receiving data.

Before I start explaining how I tried to diagnose the problem, I will share how it is connected and what is the code for testing the module.

**How it is connected**
[image]

**Test Code**

```python
from machine import Pin,UART
uart = UART(0, baudrate=9600, tx=Pin(16), rx=Pin(17))

while True:
    if uart.any():
        data = uart.readline()
        print(data)
```

Every time I start the program I get `b'\x00'` and I didn't even send anything yet!
When I try to send data via any type of program (the Android program or my own python program it shows) nothing, like it is not receiving the data.

I don't know if it is a problem in the *HC-06* itself or some glitch, but here is what I have tried to do:

- Try to receive data by connecting the *HC-06* to an *Arduino UNO* - Have to say that it was a nightmare to do and until I finally connected it I could not receive any data.
- Check if the `RXD` leg gets enough voltage - I have measured and it gets a little over 3.3 volts.

I would not be able to get another module for the next couple of days to try and see if it's a problem only in this module, so if it is fixable and someone has an answer, I would be happy to hear it.